Composite annotation with Multiple Simple annotation with different Applicationcontextinitializer (testcontainers)
It is possible to use the annotation composition with annotations that refer to different ApplicationContextInitializer that are in charge of starting the testcontainers of different images ?
Example
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@KafkaTestcontainers
@PostgresqlTestcontainers
public @interface CompositeAnnotation

